# How do I get the selected element by name and then get the selected value from a dropdown using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, select

I am able to find my select element by name, but I'm having trouble finding the selected value associated with it.

Here is my code below:

```
<select  name="a[b]" onchange='mySelectHandler("a[b]")'>
     <option value='Choice 1'>Choice 1</option>
     <option value='Choice 2'>Choice 2</option>

</select>
```

then, in my handler I am using:

```
function mySelectHandler(name){
     var mySelect = $('select[name=' + name)
     // try to get selected value
     // alert ("selected " + mySelect.val())
     console.log("object "+ mySelect.toSource());
  }
```

The result of my print to the log is:

object ({length:0, prevObject:{0:({}), context:({}), length:1}, context:({}), selector:"select[name=a[b]"})

Any ideas as to how to do this?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Your selector is a little off, it's missing the trailing `]`

```
var mySelect = $('select[name=' + name + ']')
```

you may also need to put quotes around the name, like so:

```
var mySelect = $('select[name="' + name + '"]')
```

Answer (score 14):

Try this:

```
$('select[name="' + name + '"] option:selected').val();
```

This will get the selected value of your menu.

Comment: how can get all the names??

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `onchange` event from the HTML Markup and bind it in your document ready event

```
<select  name="a[b]" >
     <option value='Choice 1'>Choice 1</option>
     <option value='Choice 2'>Choice 2</option>
</select>​
```

and Script

```
$(function(){    
    $("select[name='a[b]']").change(function(){
       alert($(this).val());        
    }); 
});
```

Working sample : http://jsfiddle.net/gLaR8/3/

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
mySelect.toSource()
```

use

```
mySelect.val()
```

Answer (score 0):

MrOBrian's answer shows why your current code doesn't work, with the missing trailing `]` and quotes, but here's an easier way to make it work:

```
onchange='mySelectHandler(this)'
```

And then:

```
function mySelectHandler(el){
     var mySelect = $(el)
     // get selected value
     alert ("selected " + mySelect.val())
  }
```

Or better still, remove the inline event handler altogether and bind the event handler with jQuery:

```
$('select[name="a[b]"]').change(function() {
    var mySelect = $(this);
    alert("selected " mySelect.val());
});
```

That last would need to be in a document.ready handler or in a script block that appears after the select element. If you want to run the same function for other selects simply change the selector to something that applies to all, e.g., *all* selects would be `$('select')`, or all with a particular class would be `$('select.someClass')`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get value from select element by Element Name

```
$("select[name=elementnamehere]").val();
```

Answer (score 0):

or you can simply do

```
$('select[name=a[b]] option:selected').val()
```

Answer (score 0):

To add to the answers here, ensure there's no space between the `select` and `[name...`

**Wrong:**

```
'select [name=' + name + ']'
       ^
```

**Right:**

```
'select[name=' + name + ']'
```