# jQuery selector for <select multiple="multiple" name="formCountries[]">

Tags: jquery, arrays, select, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to write a form validation and I'm stuck with writing a selector for this select-option element without any other attribute.

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="formCountries[]">
```

How can I do this?

Comment: So, what stops you from adding a class or id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get the selected element by name and then get the selected value from a dropdown using jQuery?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909109/how-do-i-get-the-selected-element-by-name-and-then-get-the-selected-value-from-a)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this. See [**Attribute Selector**](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/)

```
$('select[multiple = multiple][name="formCountries[]"]').change(function() {


});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [attribute selector](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/attribute-selectors/) to select by name. You have to escape the square brackets which could be done by wrapping the name in quotes.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/zm5tM/)**

```
var sel = $('[name="formCountries[]"]');
```

Comment: Thank you.I didn't think of using commas for the attribute selector.

Comment: You are welcome, these quotes are used to escape the square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#btn').click(function(){
       alert('ding '+$('select').val());
     });
   });
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <input type="button" id="btn"/>
  <select multiple="multiple" name="formCountries[]">
   <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
   <option value="saab">Saab</option>
   <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
   <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </select>
 </body>
</html>
```